# unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary while attempting Maven test on Jenkins using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Had been trying to configure and have met with a lot of trouble, tried a lot of attempt but failed.

- chromedriver=2.30.477691
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115
- Build info: version: '3.14.0'
- Selenium 3.4
- java.version: '1.8.0_121'
- Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64

Error:

```
unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: '8f5b40c32460', ip: 'x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: '8f5b40c32460', ip: 'x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.30*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.30*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v58-60**

- You are using *chrome=59.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.14.0* of *2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z* which is almost **2.5** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_121** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between *JDK v8u121* , *Selenium Client v3.14.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.30* and the *Chrome Browser v59.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u232](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: `unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '8f5b40c32460', ip: '172.18.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver`
  
I tried to update everything but eventhough i upgrade my java.version on my linux, it do not show on jenkins. May i ask how to fix this?