# Linux and Selenium - cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a similar problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054901/unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-while-attempting-maven-test-on-jenkins#60055268):

That thread has a thoroughly explained solution, even if it's a few years old. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have a maven project, with a spring-boot application and a suite of Selenium/Cucumber tests in Java/Kotlin.

After upgrading to a newer OS (Fedora), I'm getting this error when I try to start any Selenium test from the IntelliJ IDEA:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

Now, the logical solution is a mismatch between the local Chrome version and Chromedriver. However, I have the EXACT same versions of these:

chromedriver:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 117.0.5938.149 (e3344ddefa12e60436fa28c81cf207c1afb4d0a9-refs/branchheads/5938@{#1539}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully
```

Chrome version:

```
Versjon 117.0.5938.149 (Offisiell delversjon) unknown (64-bit)
```

Any ideas? chromedriver is placed in /usr/share and symlinked from /usr/bin

This version of Chromedriver is, of course, a testing version. But it's stable, and I cannot see any reason why it shouldn't work at all like this. So this has to be an IntelliJ/Selenium issue, I think.

I tried adding this in VM options in the run configuration:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver
```

No change.

Comment: How and where did you install chrome itself? There is an option to specify the chrome path [manually](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chromium/ChromiumOptions.html#setBinary(java.io.File)) which you could try

Comment: The Chrome version is the one bundled with the Fedora installation.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver/01fde32d0ed245141e24151f83b7c2db31d596a4#requirements